# How to read multiple sheets in each file and convert data in synapse

Tags: csv, azure-pipelines, azure-synapse

I have multiple Excel files, each containing multiple sheets of the same format. Each Excel actually only needs sheets 2, 3, 4, and 5.
Is there a way to read in the required sheets from each Excel file or csv file in the synaspe pipeline and output each to file data?
The image is an idea of what I would like to do.

The way I am aware of is to specify the sheets, so I would like to know how to do this in one pipeline.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59hSB.png)

Comment: Are you referring to [Synapse](https://synapse.apache.org/) ?

Comment: Yes. That's right.
Sorry, I have not been able to add the tag synapse or azure tags.
I added the tags many times but could not add the synapse or azure tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can use copy activity to copy the excel sheets into csv assuming the source and the sink are supported in synapse. You can leverage the concept of sheet index in excel dataset to read specific sheets within an excel without knowing the name of the sheets